# WordPress adds <p> and <br> tags if I don't use wp_reset_postdata() in loop. Why?

Tags: wordpress, facetwp

I have a simple WordPress WP Query loop for custom post type data. Because of filtering the data with FacetWP I have to remove `wp_reset_postdata()`. Otherwise the ajax filtering is not working.

But if I remove `wp_reset_postdata()`, WordPress adds a lot of `p` and `br` tags to my HTML content. Why?

My code:

```
// WP_Query args
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'post_type' => 'abc',
    'facetwp' => true
  );

  // The Query
  $abc_query = new \WP_Query($args);
  
  // The Loop
  if ( $abc_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $abc_query->have_posts() ) {
      $abc_query->the_post();
      ?>

      <div id="abc-wrapper">
      
      <ul class="abc-list">
        <li class="abc-list-elem">
            <h4 class="abc-title">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h4>
            <span class="abc-desc">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </span>
            <?php 
                $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'abc_types');
                foreach($terms as $t) {
                    ?>
                        <span class="abc-badge">
                            <?php echo $t->name ?>
                        </span>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>



      <?php
    }
  } else {
    // There are no posts
  }

}
```

Do you have an idea why WordPress adds a lot of `p` and `br` tags if I don't reset the postdata with `wp_reset_postdata()`?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_reset_postdata` as no impact on `the_content` formating.

> After looping through a separate query, this function restores the `$post` global to the current post in the main query.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/

When you output the content, while in a loop, you can sanitize the output to remove any and all tags using `wp_strip_all_tags`.

> Properly strip all HTML tags including script and style.

```
<?php wp_strip_all_tags( the_content(), true ); ?>
```

(`true` or `false` for line breaks).

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/

Alternatively, you can remove any auto `<p>` tag applied as line break by removing the `wpautop` via `remove_filter` in your `function.php` file.

```
<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); ?>
```